# XML validating with XSD failing due to 'refname' not declared despite refname not allowed for schemas

Tags: c#, xsd, xml-validation

I am trying to validate an XML via an XSD in c# code. However it keeps throwing an **XmlSchemaValidationException**, namely "*The 'refname' attribute is not declared.*".

The code doing the validation:

```
XmlReaderSettings xmlSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            xmlSettings.Schemas = new System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet();
            xmlSettings.Schemas.Add(null, @"\\[Network-drive path]\KVSchemaMod.xsd");
            xmlSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
            xmlSettings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse;
            xmlSettings.ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.AllowXmlAttributes;
            xmlSettings.ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
            xmlSettings.ValidationFlags = XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"\\[Network-drive path]\KV_Article.xml", xmlSettings);

            // Parse the file.
            while (reader.Read()) ;
```

The XSD (with repetitous parts removed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mapping-schema">
<xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
        <sql:relationship name="ProductIdentifier"
        parent="tblKVProduct"
        parent-key="record_reference"
        child="tblKVProductIdentifier"
        child-key="record_reference" />
... (More SQL-mappings)
<xs:element name="ONIXMessage" sql:is-constant="1">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Product" sql:relation="tblKVProduct">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="RecordReference" sql:field="record_reference" >
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:minLength value="0"/>
                                    <xs:maxLength value="32"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
...(More elements under Product)
```

The XML to be validated (ONIX-standard):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ONIXMessage SYSTEM "http://www.editeur.org/onix/2.1/reference/onix-  international.dtd">
<ONIXMessage>
<Product>
    <RecordReference>0786606274</RecordReference>
    <NotificationType>03</NotificationType>
    <ProductIdentifier>
        <ProductIDType>01</ProductIDType>
        <IDTypeName>Kustantajan tuotenumero</IDTypeName>
        <IDValue>95535</IDValue></ProductIdentifier>
    <ProductIdentifier>
        <ProductIDType>02</ProductIDType>
        <IDValue>0786606274</IDValue></ProductIdentifier>
    <ProductIdentifier>
        <ProductIDType>03</ProductIDType>
        <IDValue>9780786606276</IDValue>
    </ProductIdentifier>
...(And more Product-fields)
```

The XML also has a Header tag as the first child of ONIXMessage (followed by all Product tags that as also childrens of ONIXMessage), but since none of the fields there are referenced in the schema I don't see how they could cause this particular error.

As I googled the error I read up on the XmlSchemaElement.RefName property ([MSDN Definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaelement.refname.aspx)) it even explicitly says that "*The value cannot be set if the containing element is the schema element.*"
Since that is the case for the XSD I don't understand why it throws an error about it not being declared.

I've been trying to find out if this could be related to the lack of namespace, but in my mind that shouldn't be a problem since there is none in neither the XML nor the XSD. Or does one need to force a namespace onto the root-element in order to validate the XML?

The validating code does work with another set of XML/XSD (very different build-up on those though), could that just be a fluke though and the error actually in the way I validate?

Just for completion's sake, the Header tag in the XML:

```
<Header>
    <FromCompany></FromCompany>
    <FromPerson></FromPerson>
    <FromEmail></FromEmail>
    <AddresseeIdentifier>
        <AddresseeIDType></AddresseeIDType>
        <IDTypeName></IDTypeName>
        <IDValue></IDValue>
    </AddresseeIdentifier>
    <ToCompany></ToCompany>
    <ToPerson></ToPerson>
    <MessageNumber></MessageNumber>
    <SentDate></SentDate>
    <MessageNote></MessageNote>
</Header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to reproduce your problem, given that you haven't provided a complete example.  If you want answers based on anything other than speculation, you need to cut down your schema and your data to the smallest example that illustrates the problem, so question answerers can reproduce the problem and study it in more detail.  It will often happen, of course, that your problem dissolves in the process because you come to see what's going wrong in the process of finding a small example of the problem.  But that's just a risk you have to take.

That said, however, I'll go ahead and speculate.  The RefName property on the XMLSchemaElement object is almost certainly a red herring.  The message makes it sound much more as if the XML you are attempting to validate has an attribute named `refname` somewhere (in the bit you elided), and your XSD schema has no definition for it.  Certainly the XSD fragment you provide has no definition for it.

The vocabulary defined at http://www.editeur.org/onix/2.1/reference/onix-international.dtd (which you point to in your XML), however, does define `refname` as an attribute on many elements (probably all of them, though I haven't checked each one individually).  So it's not at all implausible that an ONIXMessage element might contain a descendant with a `refname` attribute.

Actually, it's not just not implausible; it's certain.

The DTD pointed to by your XML supplies a default value for the `refname` attribute on all elements (at least, all the ones I've seen), for which your XSD schema declaration appears not to be prepared.  That is, the first start-tag of your document seen by the schema validator is not `<ONIXMessage>` but `<ONIXMessage refname="ONIXMessage" shortname="ONIXmessage">`.

If you're not using the XSD available from www.editeur.org, the simplest way forward is probably to reconsider that decision and use the schema from editeur.org instead of rolling your own.  It includes declarations for the refname and shortname attributes.  If you *are* using that schema, or rather trying to use it, something has gone badly wrong and your validator is not finding or reading it.  In that case, your best way forward is to figure out why your system is not finding the correct schema documents.

Comment: For some reason I never considered using 2 different schemas, one for validating (from Editeur) and one for the Bulkload (in-house version).
Thank you so much for speculating even though I failed to construct an acceptable question! =)
Works like a charm.